aws.LogResponse does not seem to log all responses during errors
It does not seem like aws.LogResponse logs all HTTP responses with an error.
I have my s3 client configured this way -
        cfg, err = config.LoadDefaultConfig(
            ctx,
            config.WithClientLogMode(aws.LogRetries|aws.LogRequest|aws.LogResponse),
            config.WithLogger(smithyLogger),
            config.WithHTTPClient(httpClient), 
            config.WithRetryer(func() aws.Retryer {
                return retry.NewStandard(func(o *retry.StandardOptions) {
                    o.RateLimiter = ratelimit.None 
                })
            }),
            config.WithAPIOptions(middlewareStacks),
        )

When I run my application, I can see HTTP responses being logged -
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nDate: Wed, 16 Oct 2024 19:17:56 GMT\r\nEtag: \"f80be8g32671a6f7604b1b9ddff58e55\"\r\nServer: SomeServer\r\nVary: Origin\r\nX-Amz-Request-Id: 28GG15FE7019B03B

However, all HTTP responses are not being logged.
For example, the application logs a few of these errors which are logged after the operation response is received from the S3 API -
read tcp 253.35.233.225:53691->253.35.72.80:9554: read: connection reset by peer

However, it seems like aws.LogResponse never logs these errors. It only logs a few of these 500 status code errors -
TTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 365\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nContent-Type: application/xml\r\nDate: Wed, 16 Oct 2024 19:38:54 GMT\r\nServer: SomeServer\r\nVary: Origin\r\nX-Amz-Request-Id: 2GGG1731EDFE13FB

How can I accurately log all HTTP requests and responses made by the S3 APIs?
